# How to access a static method in a different static class in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a helper class for accessing the database, however I can't access it from the code portion in my razor page

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using OsrsPriceHistory.Models;

namespace OsrsPriceHistory.Helpers
{
    public static class DBConnection
    {
        private static OsrsDatabaseSettings databaseSettings = new OsrsDatabaseSettings();
        private static MongoClient? mongoClient;
        public static IMongoDatabase getDatabase()
        {
            if (mongoClient == null)
            {
                mongoClient = new MongoClient(databaseSettings.ConnectionString);
            }

            var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("OsrsPrices");

            return database;
        }
    }
}
```

and another class (razor page) I am trying to access the static method in

```
@page "/"
@using OsrsPriceHistory.Helpers

<PageTitle>Prices</PageTitle>

<h1> Prices</h1>



@code {
  
    DBConnection.


}
```

However I get the error "The name 'DBConnection' does not exist in the current context and the error "The name 'getDatabase' does not exist in the current context."

I'm unsure what's wrong since I seem to be implementing static correctly

Comment: This really shouldn't be a static class, this should be a service which you should inject using the @inject tag and resolve the dependency  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0services

Comment: The reason you are not able to access DBConnection is because you are not able to create an instance of a static class.